# How can I access to change styles of inner items of a component in react and material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I access to inner css classes of children of a component and add or change styles to/of them? like I want to change and customize material ui stepper steps circle font size and color and so on.

How can I write css classes like bellow:

```css
.stepper circle { 
  font-size:18px;
}
```

or

```css
.stepper .text {
  font-size:18px;
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @spakmad's answer, but that's not exactly what I meant, maybe my question was not clear enough. I meant how to write above mentioned CSSs in material ui object style classes format(classes injected with withStyle HOC).

I found my solution:

```js
stepper:{
  '& circle':{
      fontSize: '18px'
    }
}
```

and

```js
stepper: {
  '& .text': {
    fontSize: '18px'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The very straightforward way to do it without having to worry about classes is by using the `material-ui` `style` prop. Like so,

`<Stepper style={{ fontSize: '18px' }} />`

This applies a style to the root element, which I assume to be a `div` or container of sorts, although it probably varies by the component.

More specifically, and what you probably want to do is use `material-ui` `classes` prop. That is, since you know exactly what classes you want to override, you can do so as follows,

`<Stepper classes={{ text: { fontSize: '18px' }}} />`

I use `text` here as a classname because in the question, `.text` appears to reference and already existing class. Since you're trying to increase the size of the font in this `svg` that comes with the `Stepper`. You'll need to get the class name applied to the `svg` and override it. In this case, one of its classnames is `MuiSvgIcon-root-184` so you would expect to be able to do,

`<Stepper classes={{ MuiSvgIcon-root-184: { fontSize: '18px' }}} />`

This classname however is generated by `material-ui` dynamically based on the layout resulting from props and could be different across all renders.

---

TLDR

So, trusty `className` component and writing some css and component JSX as follows.

`<Stepper className={'customStepper'} />`

```
.customStepper svg: {
   font-size: '18px !important',
}
```

You need to include `!important` to make sure this style is respected. Material UI by default puts its styles last in the document so they're normally overwriting anything else, but the `!important` spec should override the override.